# Importing date data from excel into table with right format conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, date

I am importing data from excel files into SQL server database. In excel ,Date field are in the format mm-dd-yyyy. Whereas SQL database imports it as yyyy-mm-dd, swapping dates to months.For ex. in excel its 01-12-2018 but in SQL it imports as 2018-12-01.  Hence the dates are incorrect.

Please let me know a way to import it correctly in SQL.
I am happy to import in both ways : yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy-dd-mm. I just want it to read the date correctly form excel file.

I am using import export wizard.

Comment: a solution could be to properly format cells in excel, chosing (for example) the yyyy-MM-dd format. For general purposes: normalize your data, then import them in a relational database

Comment: Are both fields in SQL and in Excel formatted as date?

Comment: *Hence the dates are incorrect.* - if the dates are following the required format they are correct. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Dates have no inherent format. Are you Excel values actually strings rather than date values?

Comment: How are you importing them, and what is the extension on the file that you are importing?

Comment: @vitalaya yes , both are dates. dates are incorrect as in in sql table its reading dates as months. So whenever date is above 12 the format in sql is yyyy-mm-dd otherwise its yyyy-dd-mm. Hope that make sense.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Importing using Import export wizard and extension is - xlsx.

Comment: @B3S Thanks for your reply. But I would like to learn a way to do such import in sql when its not possible to change it in source excel.

Comment: @DavidG they are dates not strings

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer:**
OP mentioned in another answer comment

> I am currently using import export wizard to import data.

To solve problem in Import export wizard.

1. Choose Flat file source - I used a sample file (sample.csv) with this data

   id, dates, text
   1,08-09-2018,"sample"
   2,05-09-2019,"more sample"
   [image: Choose data step- advanced tab]
2. Under Choose your data source I went to Advanced tab and ensured that dates are imported as string.
   [image]
3. At the Select Source Table and Views step, go into Edit Mappings>Edit SQL and then change the table creation query to have an extra calculated column (say `cdates`) with definition like `[cdates] as convert(date,[ dates],110)`. As you can see I added this in my SQL as last column in definition.

In the case that you don't create table but insert into existing table. Alter the table to have a calculated column over the varchar date column.

See the output I got
[image]

**Original Answer:**
You should import the dates as nvarchar(10) into the table and then cast them after they have been imported.

Typically nvarchar type structure is followed for all purpose and is also called staging tables. In staging tables most of the relevant mistrusted data fields are of nvarchar(N) type allowing them to be successfully imported into SQL server.

After import, you should take data from staging tables into desired tables using properly casted/converted columns in a MERGE or UP-SERT query.

In you case you should use explicit convert like

```
CONVERT(date,your_staging_date_column ,110)
```

Comment: This sounds like a pretty bad idea, the values should either be in the right format to start with (i.e. in Excel as actual dates) or converted as they are imported. To stage the values elsewhere is a waste of resource.

Comment: @DavidG It's a common thing to do and has it's usefulness in ETL process. [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_(data)]

Comment: I'm well aware of what staging data is, I'm saying that for such a simple conversion that it's a complete waste of time.

Comment: @DavidG Well if the OP has work to do in excel and still does not get results, it's better to at least stage once and get the conversion straight and then from next time skip staging altogether

Comment: @DavidG I to a certain extent believe that OP has bad data with both mm-dd and dd-mm data present in the column.

Comment: @DavidG On other note, *I do believe what you say is correct*. It is a waste to stage data for a single column with a straightforward conversion

Comment: @DhruvJoshi any other idea than staging table. Can i just import in sql table and then apply a conversion ?

Comment: @user8165644 Yes you can do that. If it's a one off import, copy data in to SSMS and create an insert query into a temp table. Once done inserting into temp table, apply `select ''''+convert(date, temptablename.colname, 110) from temptabelname` and then copy the results and paste the results back into excel.

Comment: thanks @DhruvJoshi . No its a daily import of multiple excel files. Can i do something using SSIS?

Comment: @user8165644 If it's a daily thing, then definitely SSIS

Comment: @DhruvJoshi sorry i meant to ask , what to do in SSIS? Where to put this convert function while importing?

Comment: @user8165644 So I read elsewhere that you are using import export wizard. I'm going to answer based on that.

Comment: @user8165644 Updated my answer. Do check.

Comment: Please accept(and up-vote) my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

If data is set as Date in Excel, you can convert it to nvarchar, and then back to date as follows:

```
CONVERT(date, convert(nvarchar, [date from excel]), 110);
```

110 in the end means that it will convert from format mm-dd-yyyy as your data is currently formatted in Excel.

If you are reading data from Excel as pure text, then it will be enough to convert that text to date:

```
CONVERT(date, [date from excel], 110);
```

This function will convert data to correct format in your table.

Comment: Do you mean i apply these conversions after data is imported in sql table?

Comment: Apply conversion in importing step. Just when using this date field, instead of just setting value to what's in the field, call the above conversion

Comment: I am currently using import export wizard to import data. Where can i use this in there please?